# Returning a 1D array in Excel 2016

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2016

I've been trying to figure out how to return arrays from VBA functions. I came across this site: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx which provides some useful examples, notably this one:

```
Function Test() As Variant
    Dim V() As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    ReDim V(1 To 3, 1 To 4)
    For R = 1 To 3
        For C = 1 To 4
            N = N + 1
            V(R, C) = N
        Next C
    Next R
    Test = V
End Function
```

When I type `=Test()` into vertical range of cells with `ctrl+shift+enter` I get the expected result:

```
1
5
9
```

But what if I want to return a 1D array? I tried modifying the function to make V a 1D array:

```
Function Test() As Variant
    Dim V() As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    ReDim V(1 To 3)
    For R = 1 To 3
        For C = 1 To 4
            N = N + 1
            V(R) = N
        Next C
    Next R
    Test = V
End Function
```

Now when I enter this into the same vertical range I get this:

```
4
4
4
```

Why is this happening, and where is this behaviour documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First *TRANSPOSE()* the 1-D array:

```
Function Test() As Variant
    Dim V() As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    ReDim V(1 To 3)

    For R = 1 To 3
        For C = 1 To 4
            N = N + 1
            V(R) = N
        Next C
    Next R
    Test = Application.Transpose(V)
End Function
```

Then in the worksheet select three vertical cells and **array enter**:

```
=test()
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up question; if it really just the case that I'm looking in the wrong dimension, why does it then populate the out of bounds range with `4 4 4`, rather than `4 #N/A #N/A` like any other array function?

Comment: @quant  I don't understand your follow-up question.............generally speaking, if I am making a *UDF()* that returns an array, I use a *2-D* array.

Answer (score 1):

because it is defaulted to fill across columns instead of rows.

try

```
=TRANSPOSE(Test())
```

if you want to fill down the rows.

if you want to change the default programably, you can also do

```
Function Test()
    .
    .
    .
    Test = Worksheetfunction.Transpose(V)
End Function
```